# \iffalse not working inside of table

Tags: tables, conditionals, compilation-error, ifthenelse

The following code is supposed to generate a table with a single row and two columns. It does however not compile. The error messages contains `Incomplete \iffalse` and `A forbidden control sequence occurred in skipped text`. It compiles and the output is as expected if I use `\iftrue` or if I delete the `\iffalse ... \fi` block.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r|l}
    First column 
    \iffalse
        &  should be hidden \\ 
    \fi
        &  should be visible 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

It appears as if I am not allowed to skip some of the control sequences `&` or `\\`. But then how can I achieve the intended result? I want to toggle the appearence of the first column. I cannot move `&` or `\\` outside of the block for that purpose.

Comment: `\iffalse\@firstofone{& should be hidden \\}\fi`. You have to "hide" the `&` inside of braces.

Comment: Thank you, that works! Can you elaborate on why this is necessary and what `\@firstofone` does?

Comment: It is necessary because TeX sort-of ignores `&` in braces in a `\halign` (bad explanation, see some bigger documentation like the TeXbook or TeX by Topic). If `\makeatletter` is active the `\@firstofone` would "unpack" the braced material (so `\@firstofone{<stuff>}` results in `<stuff>`), which would be necessary if the `\iffalse` was some real test that might as well evaluate to true. If you only want to "comment out" your table in an `\iffalse` you could use `\iffalse{& should be hidden\\}\fi` as well (but how is that better than `% & should be hidden\\ `).